# How could i change doctype of a html file using invokeScript in wp7 or wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am rendering  a html file and this file is having different doctype how could i change its doctype same as html 5 doctype using web browser InvokeScript method.

Comment: Where did you get that file? Are you loading it from the isolated storage or from string or from URL?

Comment: these html files are stored into isolated storage to render these files i am using myWebBrowser.Navigate("here is uri");

Comment: On myWebBrowser.Navigate_Completed in want to change its doctype...

Comment: Then you can simply change that file yourself. After all, it is in *your* storage and it is just a text file.